# Ensure file upload on Google Drive C#

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am developing C# Windows application that will upload files to Google Drive. I need to be sure about the file that has been uploaded on Google Drive in case of any failures.

I want to avoid situations where i.e File started uploading but internet went off and only part of the file got uploaded.

How can I compare that files got transferred to Google Drive without any problems.

Below is the code that I use to upload the files to Google Drive.

```
public static File uploadFile(DriveService _service, string _uploadFile, string _parent)
{
     if (System.IO.File.Exists(_uploadFile))
     {
          File body = new File();
          body.Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_uploadFile);
          body.Description = "File uploaded by Diamto Drive Sample";
          body.MimeType = GetMimeType(_uploadFile);
          body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = _parent } };

          // File's content.
          byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_uploadFile);
          System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
          try
          {
              FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = _service.Files.Insert(body, stream, GetMimeType(_uploadFile));
              request.Upload();

              Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = request.ResponseBody;
              Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.Permission newPermission = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.Permission();
              newPermission.Value = "123@gmail.com";
              newPermission.Type = "anyone";
              newPermission.Role = "writer";
              _service.Permissions.Insert(newPermission, file.Id).Execute();

              return request.ResponseBody;
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
             return null;
         }
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("File does not exist: " + _uploadFile);
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Comment: It will return HTTP 409 if it fails or you will get an exception for the client side. You can retry uploads with pregenerated ID see [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-uploads#resumable) for more detailed information.

Comment: @Berkays Thanks for the tip. but right now when the file is uploaded successfully then also i am getting response body as NULL. So i would never know about the id. Thats why i was thinking to check manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register for the `ProgressChanged` event and check the `UploadStatus` property for confirming a successful upload.

```
request.ProgressChanged += UploadProgessEvent;
```

and

```
private void UploadProgessEvent(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress obj)
{
    if (obj.Status == Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus.Completed)
    {
        //Succesfully Uploaded
    }
}
```

There is also a `BytesSent` property in `IUploadProgress` that you can compare with the original file size for checking upload completion.

---

However, as mentioned in the answer referenced by KENdi, from the [`insert` Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert),

> If successful, this method returns a Files resource in the response body.

Exceptions will be thrown if upload fails by any reason and `catch` block must handle it.

Comment: I think the progress changed event will help. I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check this related SO question if it can help you to determine if the file upload is successful.

- [Is there a way to check if a file is successfully uploaded with Google Drive API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538889/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-successfully-uploaded-with-google-drive-api)

Now, about the file upload that you are doing, if you want to avoid your uploading to be stopped when an internet connection is cut off, then try to use the [Resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload), This protocol allows you to resume an upload operation after a communication failure interrupts the flow of data.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142992/google-drive-resumable-upload-no-response) will show you on how to use resumable upload with C#.

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: thanks for sharing info on resumable option. I didnt knew it. One quick question though. Is it available in the V2 of the APIS ?

Comment: YES, this is the link for v2, https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/resumable-upload